# microsoft-teams: The app works in desktop teams browser but does not load on app

Tags: microsoft-teams

The custom app is working fine in teams browser, I have whitelisted "https://teams.microsoft.com" in my application code which is loaded in the teams i-frame. However, when I try to run the app on the team's APP, I am getting a blank screen.

1. do we have separate manifest file for running custom app on APP?
2. what is the whitelisted URL should i put in my code to load my application in teams app?

Comment: Are you trying to load on the page using tab or inside a task module? Could you please share more details?